# Implementing Google Maps API Key into Java Project using Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, google-maps, vaadin

I have taken over a an ongoing project that is written in Java (something that I have no prior experience with, but I can code Python and C++) using Eclipse (which I am also new to). The project uses Vaadin components, and Eclipse runs it with glassfish which pops up a page in the browser with the results.

I have been successful in navigating myself around the code and made a few modifications, however one of them is a tiny Google Map with markers and I have having trouble displaying it. The previous owner has already set up a Google Maps API for it. When I run the code in Eclipse, the result appears with a link that starts with "localhost:8080..." which does not display the Google Map ("Oops something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps correctly. See the Javascript console for technical details."). The API become accessible to the component when I switch "localhost" with the IP of the computer, and the map displays.

I am trying to replace the API key of the previous owner of the project with one that I have just acquired here at [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). While I have also searched and found many examples that are very similar to [this one](https://www.latecnosfera.com/2016/06/google-maps-api-error-missing-keymap-error-solved.html), I cannot locate any javacript files within the project via Eclipse that I can apply the solution with.

With the ultimate goal for this is to host the exported .war file on a server, any help on how to locate the link between the code and the API key is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [this semi-official addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/googlemaps-add-on) instead of trying to roll your own. It allows you to give the API key directly in the component constructor.

You should check out the [Vaadin add-on directory](https://vaadin.com/directory) for other needs as well, it has hundreds of useful addons for many purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention the google map component  in my question is implemented using the Googlemap addon. The above described scenario was produced with a null value for where the apikey is suppose to be in the constructor (which according to the many discussions that I have read, this should be fine for localhost, however not for me). I have also tried to put the apikey that I have acquired myself in that field, but only a blank grey screen has appeared (without that standard google warning message) for the part where the Google map should be.